# JQuery Attribute Contains Selector does not work in WebKit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, attributes, webkit

I have a javascript visualization that produces a set of circles, some of which (given the fileTag attribute value "current advertising") should be visible by default, some of which (given the fileTag attribute value "past advertising") should not. An example circle looks like this:

```
<circle id="986" class="node" style="cursor: pointer; fill: rgb(171, 183, 71); display: block;" title="Title" r="6.345236822911981" fileTags="BRAND, CURRENT ADVERTISING" fileType="Print" fileDescription="Example" cx="833.5761873699519" cy="344.6269837191289">
```

To achieve this, I use the following code:

```
$( ".node[fileTags*='PAST ADVERTISING']" ).css("display", "none");
$( ".node[fileTags*='CURRENT ADVERTISING']" ).css("display", "inline");
$( ".node:not([fileTags*='ADVERTISING'])" ).css("display", "none");
```

This works as expected in Firefox, Opera, and Internet Explorer. In Safari/Chrome, however, all circles are hidden (using the code as a above) or all circles are displayed (if I remove the third line with the :not).

Have I done something wrong in my code, or is this a WebKit bug? If the latter, any thoughts on a work-around?

Comment: How about doing it the old fashion way -> http://jsfiddle.net/VV6Cf/

Comment: @adeneo - Sometimes the old fashioned way is the best way. Had to do a little fooling around with getting the fileTag (it kept throwing undefined as written, but that may be a peculiarity of my environment, rather than a problem with your code) - but with that done, your code snippet solved my practical problem. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have heard the not selector can have mixed results...

I haven't tried it yet but have you tried something like:

```
$( ".node[fileTags*='PAST ADVERTISING']" ).css("display", "none");
$( ".node[fileTags*='CURRENT ADVERTISING']" ).css("display", "inline");
$( ".node" ).not("[fileTags*='ADVERTISING']").css("display", "none");
```

Edit:

The .not() method will end up providing you with more readable selections than pushing complex selectors or variables into a :not() selector filter. In most cases, it is a better choice.
via http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: As written, that version of things results in all circles being invisible in all browsers. Which is technically more consistent, but not the outcome I had in mind.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g30rg3/nM2wh/ ... I was actually only able to get my solution to work in Chrome. Neither my suggestion or your original code worked in ff or IE.

Comment: That's odd, since as I said in my question, my original code *does* work in IE/FF in its working context. I wonder what is different with your implementation of it...

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.9.1